# Automating MailChimp Inbox Inspections with Grunt

Tags: email, gruntjs, mailchimp, inbox, inspection

I want to take my email build process a step further by being able to send test emails to an Inbox Inspection in MailChimp as I put the templates together.

A quick search brings up some MailChimp based Grunt tasks like this one: https://github.com/h0lyalg0rithm/grunt-mandrill This uses the Mandrill API to send out a test email to a specified email address.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

  grunt.initConfig({
    mandrill: {
      mailer: {
        options: {
          key: 'your-mandrill-API-key',
          sender: 'send@email.com',
          recipient: 'recieve@email.com',
          subject: 'This is a test email'
        },
        src: ['templates/*.html']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mandrill');
  });
```

That's almost what I'm after but not quite. Is it possible to make this work? Any help is gratefully recieved.

Comment: I imagine your best bet would be to fork this on Github and adjust it for your needs.

Comment: @MatthewDaly You're probably right, but it's getting it work with Inbox Inspections is the tricky part. There doesn't seem to be any documentation around. And I wouldn't know where to start with the API.

Comment: The API documentation doesn't seem to mention the inbox inspections, so it doesn't seem like that approach will be useful. However, from reading the docs it looks like the service is powered by Litmus, and there's a [grunt-litmus](https://github.com/jeremypeter/grunt-litmus) task, so maybe that's worth looking at. Of course, Litmus is a paid service, so using it directly is going to require shelling out for an account. It might be worth getting in touch with Mailchimp directly to ask whether it would be practical to integrate the inbox inspections with a custom Grunt task.